# Android HttpGet Url causes "Illegal Character at Index 110" error

Tags: indexing, character, foursquare

I'm trying to instantiate an HttpGet Object so that I can send a get request to the foursquare api. However, every time I attempt this, (and I've tried it with several different tokens) I get the following error:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 110:         https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?oauth_token=VIHXZZH1ZEXTXOYDFRHHWF42YREWKMNTABDTTVMMF3CSYTKW

It's in the format https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?oauth_token=OAUTH_TOKEN. You can see my code below. Thanks in advance.

```
String checkinsUrl = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins";  
String authUrl = checkinsUrl + "?oauth_token=" + this.token;
HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(authUrl);
```

Comment: That string doesn't have an index 110, it's exactly 110 characters. Is there some additional part of it that you're omitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually just me being stupid. Foursquare sends back a code with is **not** the access token. You must then make an httpget with that code in order to get the access token.